# Integrating $\int \sqrt{(2+\sin{3x})\cos{3x}}{dx}$

Tags: integration

Integrating $$\int \sqrt{(2+\sin{3x})\cos{3x}}\mathrm{d} x$$

Let, $\sqrt{2+\sin{3x}}=t$

then, $\frac{3\cos{3x}}{2\sqrt{2+\sin{3x}}}\mathrm{d} x=\mathrm{d} t$

Integral = $\frac{2}{3}\int\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{1-(t^2-2)^2}}\mathrm{d} t$

Integral = $\frac{2}{3}\int\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{1-(t^2-2)}\sqrt{1+(t^2-2)}}\mathrm{d} t$

Comment: Is the $\cos(3x)$ also inside the square root?

Comment: Yes. The $\cos(3x)$ is inside the square root.

Comment: This will involve elliptic integrals. My first attempt yielded extremely messy expressions that are not very easy to simplify...

Answer (score 1):

Some idea: by parts

$$u:=t\;\;,\;\;u'=1\\v'=\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-(t^2-2)^2}}\;\;,\;\;v=\frac{1}{2}\arcsin(t^2-2)$$

so

$$\frac{2}{3}\int\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{1-(t^2-2)^2}}dt=-\frac{1}{3}t\arcsin(t^2-2)-\frac{1}{3}\int\arcsin(t^2-2) dt\ldots$$